# Mac OS X 10.8 Server File Sharing is strangely slow

Tags: mac, file-sharing, osx-mountain-lion

I work in a small company as a web designer/developer and part of my job is server administration. I am not a professional administrator and most of my knowledge I pick up while working. 
So, the network in the company is small and not very complex, although it used to be more chaotic. Not the problem is, or better to say: what I believe is the root of the problem is that the servers are macs. I was tasked to move the server from one macmini that ran on OS X 10.5 to a newer one that runs on 10.8, and after many a headache, I managed to do so. 
But now, I just can't manage to see where the problems lie anymore. So after this brief assessment of the situation, here's the problem:

The old server was connected to a RAID system that carries the company data. It ran well and agreeably fast. Now when I set out to move this to the new server, I thought it would be simple enough: connect the RAID to the new mac, set up rights and smb and it's done - it's not like the mac allows for many more settings. I was wrong though - and after even more struggles, it ran. But it all seems in vain now, because the performance is inconsistent and very bad at times, meaning far too long waiting periods to access data. The connection to the network is still the same though, as is the RAID's connection to the new server. So there shouldn't be a problem there.

Did I forget to do something? Does the RAID have some dependency I don't know about? 
I'm kind of lost here, so thank you in advance for any advice.

Just some infos about the server:

- Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion
- Services Running:

  - File Sharing
  - DNS
  - FTP
  - Open Directory
  - Software Updates
  - VPN
  - Kerio Connect Mail and Exchange Server
- Hardware

  - Processor: 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
  - 4 GB DDR3 1067MHz Ram